# Validação de Recaptcha não funciona

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso fazer a validação do Recaptcha em um form. Mas, não está funcionando.

```js
function validaCaptchaContato() {
  if(document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-contato').value == '') {
     alert('Marque a opção "Não sou um robô"');
     return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form-contato" onsubmit="return validaCaptchaContato();">
 BLABLABLABLA
 <label>
  <textarea class="fields textarea" name="mensagem" placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem." required></textarea>
 </label>
 <div class="captchaFix">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="COPIEI CERTO"></div>
 </div>
 <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" name="enviar" id="g-recaptcha-contato" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: qual o erro está acontecendo? o que exatamente não está funcionando?

Answer (score 0):

Bloquei o botão de enviar e utilize o atributo `data-callback`, dessa forma quando o usuário realizar a verificação, o botão será liberado.

```js
function enableButton() {
  document.querySelector("input[type=\"submit\"]").removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<form action="?" method="POST">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdOQBsTAAAAAHgHKPaN0mjDcEAWbC0f-YgSC65D" data-callback="enableButton"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Você também pode utilizar o método `getResponse` ao clicar no botão, dessa forma:

```js
function validation() {
  if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
    alert("Robôs não podem enviar esse formulário");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<form action="?" method="POST" onsubmit="return validation();">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdOQBsTAAAAAHgHKPaN0mjDcEAWbC0f-YgSC65D" data-callback="enableButton"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Fiz das tuas formas. Porém, ele continua enviando sem verificar o checkbox.

Comment: @FelipeStoker atualiza sua pergunta e coloca seu código, fiz baseado em um teste em localhost.